# UPDATE SQL some field with "except" Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to UPDATE sql by using "except" Conditions but it's not working.

This is sql query that I have used:

```
UPDATE `LMS_EMP` SET `email`="XXX@xXX.com" WHERE NOT `org_abbr_code` IN (HR100, HR101, HR103);
```

Here are my concept:

1.If some of fields `org_abbr_code` have these values `HR100 OR HR101 OR HR103`, the email field will not change.

2.If another `org_abbr_code`values, the email field will change as expect.

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

**I've edited for readable.

Comment: I think you are missing single quotes around the string constants.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I already try but it is not working.

Comment: Did you explicitly commit after the update?

Comment: @user9111600 String values should always be within quotes. And for all below answers it is same `WHERE NOT column_name IN ('value1', 'value2')` and `WHERE column_name NOT IN ('value1', 'value2')`

Comment: @KrishanKumarMourya Thank you for clarify, I have test withthis code and it's working UPDATE `LMS_EMP`SET `email`="XXX@XX.com" WHERE `org_abbr_code` NOT IN ('HR100', 'HR101', 'HR103'); 
I think first time I have use backtick instead of Single quotes.

Comment: this question is still considered as being open/unsolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon Linoff said, don't forget the single quote :

```
UPDATE `LMS_EMP` 
SET `email`='XXX@xXX.com' 
WHERE `org_abbr_code` NOT IN ('HR100', 'HR101', 'HR103');
```

Comment: Remove the last backticks before the semi-column.

Comment: Thanks! @Daniel.

Answer (score 2):

Following query will be helpful to you,

```
UPDATE LMS_EMP SET email="XXX@xXX.com" WHERE org_abbr_code NOT IN ("HR100", "HR101", "HR103");
```

Comment: Thanks! @Abhilash. You just made my day!

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE LMS_EMP SET email="XXX@xXX.com" WHERE org_abbr_code NOT IN ("HR100","HR101", "HR103");
```

Comment: Thanks @ Krunal. Just see your comment.

Answer (score -1):

Same query i have added below

```
UPDATE LMS_EMP SET email="XXX@xXX.com" WHERE org_abbr_code NOT IN ("HR100", "HR101", "HR103");
```

Normally you want to use double quotation while you are adding any thing in 
**NOT IN or IN** statement or else it will throw an error

Comment: Thanks! @Aravindhan. I will keep in mind.

Comment: Don't it's not true : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Comment: @DanielE. In some software like teradate will not support single quotation for set of character.  Single quotation will support for numbers . In my experience i am tell this thing and i have worked on above statement by using single quotation

Comment: It's software specific who doesn't follow the SQL specification a string should be Single Quote. And for example in ORACLE a double quote will bring you an error.

Comment: @DanielE. Thanks! Daniel to share another knowledge.

Comment: @DanielE. As you have posted the query it throwing error for this user. He is already tried by suggestion based on gordon lifoff. It's not working for him

Comment: the misplaced "not" ;)